# Story about a video game character working her way towards a world where the rules are relaxed and she can be herself

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

The character is female. She awakes in a world where she lives in a cave and it has either weird physics or weird geometry. She has to pretend not to be self-aware. She hears about a world where the rules are relaxed, and she starts working toward there. There's a world where she has to get bigger and smaller in order to move. That's about all I can remember.

Edit: I read it in an anthology. A few months ago. Some candidates include Dozier's Best of the Best, one of Strahan's "The Best SciFi and Fantasy of the Year" volumes, and The Wesleyan Anthology.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When did you read this?  Was it online, in a magazine or an anthology?  Please check out the [suggestions for story-id questions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/101407) to see if they help you recall any more details you can [edit] into your question.

Comment: Thanks DavidW; edited.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is a story called ''Bit Players'' by Greg Egan.  I read it in a story collection called ''Instantiations''.

It is as you describe.  The world where she has to get bigger or smaller to move (because the laws of physics or geometry are different) is a place where she goes to make contact with some other NPCs.  As I recall, this was done by graffiti in the toilet.

Comment: Yes! This is it. And then it looks like the follow-up is "3-adica". Thanks!

Comment: I believe https://subterraneanpress.com/magazine/winter_2014/bit_players_by_greg_egan is a legit source.

Comment: Evidence of legitimacy: https://gregegan.net/BIBLIOGRAPHY/Online.html